# Save partially completed change to work on other change

Tags: svn, version-control, branching-and-merging

I'm in the middle of a large change (let's say `ProjectA`), and have to switch gears to a different project on the same files(`ProjectB`).  I don't want my work to get into `trunk` yet, and it may be a few days before I get back to `ProjectA`.

What's the right way to set this up?   Should I create a `ProjectA` branch and check the partially completed work into it, then switch my working copy back to `trunk` and work on `ProjectB` there?

When I'm done, what do I do to merge `ProjectA` back into `trunk`?

I'm comfortable with `resolved` for conflicts, I just need to know the commands for branching, switching, and merging... If I'm even on the right track.

Currently we just do all our work in `trunk`.  If that's part of the problem, let me know.

Sorry if this is a dupe, but I've been trying to figure this out for a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that doing all your work in `trunk` is a good idea, and assuming that you don't need to switch back and forth (that is, you complete the work on `ProjectB` before returning to `ProjectA`), I would do the following:

- Record my work on `ProjectA` with

  ```
  svn diff > ProjectA-WIP.diff
  ```
- Work on `ProjectB` and then commit
- Apply your in-progress changes from `ProjectA` with

  ```
  patch -Np0 -i ProjectA-WIP.diff
  ```
- Ensure that everything is fine
- Continue working on `ProjectA`

I often follow this very same procedure. Let's say `Project A` is a new feature, and `Project B` is a bug fix; clearly I cannot mix them in the same commit, and I must fix the bug before resuming work on the new feature.

### How to solve conflicts

When conflicts are not trivial,  and `patch` is not helping you at all, you could make `svn` resolve your conflicts with a bit of trickery.

After having committed your work on `ProjectB`:

- In your working copy, go back to the revision you produced the `diff` against; it is recorded in `ProjectA-WIP.diff`:

  ```
  Index: some/src/file.c
  ===================================================================
  --- some/src/file.c (revision NNNN)
  +++ some/src/file.c (working copy)
  ```

  - If your old revision was `NNNN`, just use

    ```
    svn up -r NNNN
    ```
- Apply the patch; there won't be any conflicts this time
- Update

  ```
  svn up
  ```
- Resolve any conflicts with the help of the usual Subversion's conflict handling tools

Comment: I love that idea.  That will really get me through this today.  One thing to add, running `patch -Rp0 -i ProjectA-WIP.diff` will undo the wip, leaving my working copy 'clean' for `ProjectB` dev.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention that -- and I use it all the time